# how to convert Bitmap into a View?

Tags: java, android

I have a back.png file which I need to

1. assign to a variable and convert to bitmap
2. apply a hue function to it
3. and put it back

> ```
> a = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.back);
>
> b = Hue(a);
>
> View c = (View)findViewById(R.drawable.back);
>
> ///need to make View C = Bitmap B ... but how?
> ```

Here's my code so far, everything works, only I don't know how to assign my bitmap "b" back to view "c" ... any ideas?

Thanks!

backrepeat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

---

```
AbsoluteLayout al = (AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.setLay);
Drawable dback = al.getBackground();
a = ((BitmapDrawable)dback).getBitmap();
//b = Hue(a);
d =new BitmapDrawable(a);
al.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Edit, tired that one, but converting from a drawable to a bitmap and then back again makes it loos is tileing. I just get one bitmap stretched all over the screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wat r u doing...R.drawable.back must be a png file it cannot be a view....

i mean view u must be using would be the main view like relative,absoulte,frame etc. or an imageview....u had to have one of such views

edited-->>

d=new BitmapDrawable(bm);
rl.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

where rl is my relative layout

rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.brl);

Comment: d is a bitmapdrawable declare it lyk private BitmapDrawable d;

i've used this code many times...

Comment: oh, you mean I should take it from where it is already set as a background, i.e. in an absoulteView ?

Comment: no not exactly u can take it from many ways...u can directly take it form the drawable folder..or sdcard or intenet or camera or u can create a bitmap....as u wish but wat i've sown above is setting that bitmap to the layout background..and this is the way

Comment: hmm... tries that, see edit above, it makes the bitmap loos its tiling and just stretches it.

Comment: try this 

d.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
al.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is have an ImageView in the layout XML (in this example it has ID of image), then use

```
ImageView c = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Then you can assign the bitmap to it with

```
image.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: I do have a backrepeat.xml with the bitmap it in, see above. But if I use ImageView instead of a bitmap, then I won't be able to use it as a background for other layout...

Comment: so u want the bitmap to be used as a background right? follow my edited comment